# How to trim a string: begin immediately after the first full-stop and end at the last

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to trim a string to begin and end at specific points?

Here's an example: I would like the string (text) to begin immediately after the first full-stop and end at the last full-stop.

```
_string = "money is good. love is better. be lucky to have any. can't really have both"
```

Expected output:

```
"love is better. be lucky to have any."
```

My attempt:

```
import re
pattern = "\.(?P<_string>.*?.*?).\"
match = re.search(pattern, _string)
if match != None:
    print match.group("_string")
```

My attempt started well but stopped at the second full_stop.

Any ideas on how to arrive at the expected output?

Answer (score 5):

This will work, if there is atleast one dot in the string.

```
print _string[_string.index(".") + 1:_string.rindex(".") + 1]
#  love is better. be lucky to have any.
```

If you don't want the space at the beginning, then you strip that like this

```
print _string[_string.index(".") + 1:_string.rindex(".") + 1].lstrip()
# love is better. be lucky to have any.
```

Comment: @Tiger1 Glad to have been of help :) Well, you know the drill. Please consider accepting this answer if it helps you ;)

Comment: @Scorpion_God You still have to join the strings :)

Comment: Actually, it is still faster. Results: `(14.662811703603325, 12.32323047287241, 14.474221902703448)`. The first one is your method,  the second is mine, and the third is mine with joining.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Thanks :) But we might want to test this with strings with more fullstops in them, to come to a conclusion.

Comment: That was with 10 random strings with a length somewhere between 5 and 100.

Comment: @Scorpion_God I tried [this](http://ideone.com/znB4bN) and the results are different for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `.index()` and `.rindex()` methods with string slicing?

```
string = "money is good. love is better. be lucky to have any. can't really have both"
first_full_stop = string.index('.')
last_full_stop = string.rindex('.')
string = string[first_full_stop+1:last_full_stop+1]
```

Or you can split by full stops (this one works with any number of full stops):

```
string = "money is good. love is better. be lucky to have any. can't really have both"
string = string.split('.')
string = string[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

```
 \.(.*\.)
```

this will catch all the text except `newline` between the first and last `.`

explanation:

```
\. matches the character . literally
1st Capturing group (.*\.)
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \. matches the character . literally
```

if you do not want the space at the beginning just use this one:

```
\.\s(.*\.)
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
_string = "money is good. love is better. be lucky to have any. can't really have both"
str1 =_string[_string.find(".")+1:]
for i in range(len(str1)-1,0,-1):
if(str1[i]=='.'):
    a=str1[:i+1]
    break
print a
#love is better. be lucky to have any.
```